# Adding top and bottom imageEdgeInsets in UIButton doesn't resize the UIImage frame

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am trying to achieve something that should be, in theory, easy to achieve but I am stuck.

My main goal is achieve:

- UIButton with heigh=32 width=Variable
- ImageView in UIButton that has vertical insets of 8px, left inset of 10px to the "supeview" and 8px to the titleLabel.
- TitleLabel in UIButton with no vertical inset, the inset of 8px to the imageView and a right inset of 10px to the superview

I have been reading questions and posts and everything since fine until I try to add the image top and bottom inset: The frame heigh changes to 16 but the width is still 32 and image looks deformed. 
On the other side, if I set the contentMode to .scaleFit, the image looks fine but, because the frame is not changed I lose the horizontal insets from "superview" and titleLabel.

My failing approach is the following

```
    addImageButon.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    addImageButon.setTitle("add_image".localised, for: .normal)
    addImageButon.setImage(UIImage(named: "gallery_ic"), for: .normal)
    addImageButon.contentEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    addImageButon.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
```

By inspecting the View I can see:

[image]

and the debug output looks like that:

```
Printing description of $21:
<IosCore.RoundedActionButton: 0x1115e5910; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (15 96.5; 132 32); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x283dcbd20>>
Printing description of $22:
<UIImageView: 0x1115b1af0; frame = (10 8; 32 16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x283d3aee0>>
Printing description of $23:
<UIButtonLabel: 0x11d029270; frame = (42 7; 80 18); text = 'add photos'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x281e3acb0>>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you